# Why does the badge count in the top bar not match what is in my profile?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, user-interface

On my Stack Overflow [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2194674/somnath), We can see 16 badges. But actually when I count, there are just 14 and you can see "14 Badges" in the left corner.

> [image]

Comment: You have gotten custodian 3 times. See the "x3" behind it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have earned the Custodian badge three times. That's why it has a little "x3" out to the side.

So, the 14 distinct badges listed, plus 2 additional Custodian badges, makes a total of 16 badges.

Answer (score 1):

I count 16 badges. You have "Custodian" x3.